# stored procedure in MYsql access in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

I am creating stored procedure ,here code :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `dbnm`.`getlogin`
(
  IN uid INT,
  IN upass VARCHAR(45)
)
BEGIN

 if exists(select uphno,pass from user_master where uphno=uid and pass=upass)then
  ***true
  else
  ***false
 end if;
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

i want return value(***true or ***false) in stored procedure
from PHP by calling sp
PHP code:

```
$res = $mysqli->query('call getlogin("1","rashmi")');
```

how to acesss boolean value in PHP from sp?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I used [Google](http://www.google.com) to find [this example](http://www.rvdavid.net/using-stored-procedures-mysqli-in-php-5/).

Answer (score 0):

Check out this

[PHP + MySql + Stored Procedures, how do I get access an "out" value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48126/php-mysql-stored-procedures-how-do-i-get-access-an-out-value)

you can use

```
   $res = $mysqli->query('call getlogin("1","rashmi",@value)');
   $rs = mysql_query( 'SELECT @value' );
   while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs))
   {
    debug($row);
   }
```

Comment: Ok,Now my sp code : CREATE PROCEDURE `tracker`.`getlogin`
(
  IN uid INT,
  IN upass VARCHAR(45),
  OUT active BOOLEAN
)
BEGIN
 if exists(select uphno,pass from user_master where uphno=uid and pass=upass)then
  SELECT 1 INTO active;
  else
  SELECT 1 INTO active;
 end if;
END $$
DELIMITER                                                               hOW TO CALL IN php?

Comment: else should contain SELECT 0 INTO active;

Comment: how to call active parameter in PHP? $res = $mysqli->query('call getlogin("1","rashmi",??)');

Comment: as ur reply my code becomes  $res = $mysqli->query('call getlogin("1","rashmi",@value)');
   $rs = $mysqli->query( 'SELECT @value' );
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs))
   {
    debug($row);
    echo $row;
   } but still i m getting blank page...

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$data = $res->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);
$result = $data[0];
```

Comment: using this code:$obj=mysql_fetch_object($res);
    echo $obj; i get blank page,$obj is blank so how to solve?