# how to return count of total records from MySQL using stored procedure which returns a value

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

```
delimiter // 
create procedure sp_AttendReportCountWorkouts(OUT cnt INT) 
  begin select count(*) into cnt from workout_details; 
end;
```

I have created the above stored procedure in MySQL and I'm trying to take count of records but I am not able to get the desired result. The following is actual code on my PHP page.

```
$link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'icoachswim_sp');
if (!$link)
{
    printf("Can't connect to MySQL Server. Errorcode: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit;
}

if ($count = mysqli_query($link,"call sp_AttendReportCountWorkouts()"))
{

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example $count is just a reference to MySQL result.
Here is an idea how to process that reference and get the actual result.

```
if($result = mysqli_query($link,"call sp_AttendReportCountWorkouts()"))
{
 $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
 $count = $row[0];
}
```

Update: this is just an example assuming the stored procedure is not using out parameter:

```
create procedure sp_AttendReportCountWorkouts() 
begin
 select count(*) from workout_details; 
end;
```

With an out paramter is has to be either multi_query like other answer shows or two sequential calls:

```
$spResult = mysqli_query($link,"call sp_AttendReportCountWorkouts(@cnt)"));
// process $spResult here before executing next query
$cntResult = mysqli_query($link,"select @cnt"));
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion but still am not getting the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a previous question that addresses retrieving output variables:

[PHP + MySql + Stored Procedures, how do I get access an "out" value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48126/php-mysql-stored-procedures-how-do-i-get-access-an-out-value)