# Passing variables from SQL proceedure to PHP

Tags: php, sql, variables, procedure

I am trying to create an sql proceedure that will return the results back to the php page.

I want to be able to call the procedure as follows from the php

```
call procedure_name($var1)
```

which will run this script:

```sql
-- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- pUIGetCliStmtGenFlag
--
-- This procedure returns the status of the Trading Period:
--
-- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------


drop procedure if exists pUIGetCliStmtGenFlag;
delimiter //

create procedure pUIGetCliStmtGenFlag(
IN pTradingPeriodMonth      DATE
)
MODIFIES SQL DATA
COMMENT 'Checks if the TP has been closed'
begin

  SELECT trading_period_month, 
         dt_end, 
         amt_traded_system_ccy
  FROM   ca_trading_period
  WHERE  trading_period_month=$var1

-- If amt_traded_system_ccy is NULL give the TP an open status otherwise mark as closed

  IF amt_traded_system_ccy is NULL

    $tpstatus='open'

  ELSE

    $tpstatus='closed'

end;
//

delimiter ;
```

I then want to be able to use `$tpstatus` in the rest of the php script.

I know this is simple but this is completely new to me and I cant find the correct method

Answer (score 0):

You have to call the stored procedure from php and THEN get the values back, using OUT parameters of the procedure.

Please follow these instructions:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/48161/1291428