# php mysqli prepared statements stored procedures OUT parameter

Tags: php, stored-procedures, parameters, mysqli, prepared-statement

I've got a question that involves the use of stored procedures in mysqli prepared statements.
The code snippet I'll show does work, I'd just like to know why.
The prepared statement calls a stored procedure which takes 6 parameters, where the 6th is an OUT parameter.

```
    if (!($stmt = $this->sql->prepare("CALL registerUser(?,?,?,?,?,?);"))) { ... }
    $stmt->bind_param("issisi", $id, $email, $pwd, $ip, $actKey, $notUsed);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($isSuccessful);
    $stmt->fetch();
    $stmt->close();
    $this->sql->close();
```

The OUT parameter is binded to

```
$notUsed
```

Which does not yield any value after executing, but

```
$isSuccessful
```

which I binded to the result, does return the OUT parameter from the procedure, this return value can be 0 or 1, and I've confirmed it several times.
I just don't understand why this is happening, because the procedure doesn't produce any results.

Comment: Hard to say without knowing exactly what the procedure does.

Comment: The procedure simply inserts into a table, am I getting in bind_result the Query OK, 1 row affect? And if so, how can I make use of the OUT parameter, without using `@return` and query `SELECT @return;`, because that would mean granting select to the user, which I prefer not to.

Comment: There's [some info here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/48126/php-mysql-stored-procedures-how-do-i-get-access-an-out-value) but it doesn't address prepared statements, only `mysqli::query()`.

Comment: Yes, but it queries `SELECT @x` after calling the procedure to get the OUT parameter, which I prefer not to do. The only solution I can find for the little knowledge I have in this matter, is making another procedure which calls the one I want and then queries `SELECT @return;` or change the original procedure to return 0 or 1 itself, although I prefer the first approach which makes it more modular.