# MySQL Stored Procedure returns 0 rows

Tags: php, mysql, sql, stored-procedures, mysqli

When I call the Procedure like so in phpMyAdmin (SQL tab), it works:

```
CALL `test_discount`('022979', 1101, 1, 'W', 100, @p5); SELECT @p5 AS `discount`;
```

---

However when I call it in `PHP` like so:

```
$res = $conn->query("CALL `test_discount`('022979', 1101, 1, 'W', 100, @p5); SELECT @p5 AS `discount`;");
```

I get a syntax error: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT @p5 AS discount' at line 1`

---

How do I get this to work in PHP?

Comment: `@p5);` < remove that semi-colon and try it again.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Same issue. Syntax error near `SELECT @p5 AS discount`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that mySQL does not support multiple statements in a single `query` call: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.multiple-statement.php

E.g. Given the following code (from the link above):

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("example.com", "user", "password", "database");
$res    = $mysqli->query("SELECT 1; DROP TABLE mysql.user");
if (!$res) {
    echo "Error executing query: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
}
?>
```

You'll receive the following output:

```
Error executing query: (1064) You have an error in your SQL syntax;
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax 
to use near 'DROP TABLE mysql.user' at line 1
```

**Solution:** Use a multi-query:

```
$mysqli->multi_query( "CALL `test_discount`('022979', 1101, 1, 'W', 100, @p5); SELECT @p5 AS `discount`;" );
```

EDIT: See also:

- [PHP + MySql + Stored Procedures, how do I get access an "out" value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48126/php-mysql-stored-procedures-how-do-i-get-access-an-out-value)
- http://www.joeyrivera.com/2009/using-mysql-stored-procedures-with-php-mysqlmysqlipdo/

Example using `multi_query` to call a procedure:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli(  "HOST", "USR", "PWD", "DBNAME" );
$ivalue=1;
$res = $mysqli->multi_query( "CALL myproc($ivalue,@x);SELECT @x" );
if( $res ) {
  $results = 0;
  do {
    if ($result = $mysqli->store_result()) {
      printf( "<b>Result #%u</b>:<br/>", ++$results );
      while( $row = $result->fetch_row() ) {
        foreach( $row as $cell ) echo $cell, "&nbsp;";
      }
      $result->close();
      if( $mysqli->more_results() ) echo "<br/>";
    }
  } while( $mysqli->next_result() );
}
$mysqli->close();
```

Comment: How would i get a result for `$mysqli->multi_query( "CALL test_discount('022979', 1101, 1, 'W', 100, @p5); SELECT @p5 AS discount;" );`? Because `$res->fetch_assoc()` doesn't work...

Comment: @Borsn see the link I provided below, you'll need to use store_result. I'll update my answer with the code in that link